# Can you check if a Phone Number is a verified caller ID through the twilio-client?

Tags: node.js, twilio

I need a Twilio expert to answer a question for me if they can. I have an application I'm developing in which we want a user to be able to enter a phone number and call someone with a selected phone number as the caller ID. Trick is that caller ID must be in our account Verified Caller IDs list. Now I have found several examples and tutorials about how to do this using the Twilio SDK, however we're using that on our back-end where all our tokens are stored and Twilio-Client on the front-end. Does anyone know of a way to verify a callerID using the Twilio-Client device on the front-end? Big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Twilio Client JS SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript) is mostly concerned with placing calls using WebRTC. It does not include features for calling the regular API, including the verified caller id list.

You could do a couple of things here.

Either, before you place the call, make an ajax request to your own server and make a check there against your verified caller IDs.

Or, when the call is placed and Twilio sends the webhook to your TwiML application, check the caller ID is valid at that point. If it isn't, respond to the webhook with a message using [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say) to tell the caller they are trying to call from an invalid caller ID and then [`<Hangup/>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/hangup). If it is valid, then place the outbound call leg with [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to verify a callerID.

1. get a list of numbers from your account and loop through them as follows:
   https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/outgoing-caller-ids?code-sample=code-list-an-accounts-outgoing-caller-ids&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=6.x

   $outgoingCallerIds = $twilio->outgoingCallerIds
   ->read([], 20);
   foreach ($outgoingCallerIds as $record) {
   print $record->sid.",".$record->phoneNumber.",".$record->friendlyName;
   }
2. attempt the validate the number and watch for an error
   https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/outgoing-caller-ids#add-an-outgoing-caller-id

   try{
   $validation_request = $twilio->validationRequests
   ->create("+1".$cell, // phoneNumber
   ["friendlyName" => $name]
   );
   } catch (Throwable $e){
   $pos=(strpos($e,"Phone number is already verified") );
   if (is_numeric($pos) ) { do something }
   }